# Ramda - find like function but returning non falsy result of predicate instead of found value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Is there any function in ramda which works like `find`, but instead of found element returns the result of predicate function?

So for example `R.find(x => x === 2 ? 'two' : false, [1, 2, 3])` would return `'two'` instead of `2`

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? How is that different than `(x => x === 2 ? 'two' : false) (R.find(x => x === 2, [1,2,3]))` ? You could compose these two functions together if you wanted. Otherwise, if you show your actual code and describe what you're trying to accomplish I can probably help you more effectively.

Comment: It was just an easiest example that come to my mind. But Imagine that I pass as a predicate a function which does some heavy computation and returns value or null (or other falsy value). I want to find first non falsy result and I don't want to go through the entire list.

Comment: `find` does short-circuit.  And although predicates returning non-Booleans happen to work, it's not behavior I would want to count upon.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, if you're trying to make a function do more than one thing, or make it behave differently given different inputs, it's likely there's a better way to meet your goal.

Function composition allows you to take functions that isolate specific behaviours and combine them to create new meaningful behaviours

```
// simple function "foo"
const foo = x => x === 2 ? 'two' : false

// combine foo behaviour with simple function "find"
// creates a new simple function, "bar"
const bar = R.compose(foo, R.find(R.equals(2)))

bar([1,2,3]) // => 'two'
bar([1,3])   // => false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by keeping track of the predicate result and returning after the `find` execution. For this solution let's take advantage of that in JS the assignment is an expression. Also we are going to wrap the assignment in a lambda to make the predicate function "injectable".

```
const customFind = (predicate, list) => {
    var predicateResult
    R.find((a) => predicateResult = predicate(a), list)
    return predicateResult
}
```

Example usage

```
console.log(customFind(x => x === 2 ? 'two' : false, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Furthemore, I recommend to `curry` the custom function to make it composable.

```
const customFind = R.curry((predicate, list) => {
    var predicateResult
    R.find((a) => predicateResult = predicate(a), list)
    return predicateResult
})
```

Now it can be partialy applied

```
const findTwoOrFalse = customFind(x => x === 2 ? 'two' : false)

findTwoOrFalse([1, 2, 3]) // 'two'
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Sorry to disturb you... I would like have your feedback on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229131/using-ramdajs-for-renaming-properties-of-an-object Once again thanks for providing sharing your expertise with ramdajs